# Ionic App with GA4 and FB Pixel with GTM not working in the version iOS

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I have an application in ionic framework (version 7) with capacitor, at this moment I am integrating GA4 and FB Pixel with GTM (Google Tag Manager) in android it works perfectly but when I go to the iOS branch (they have the same configurations, it only differs in one library) when inspect the app on the device, it executes the request and returns a 200 success but when I check in GA4 and FB Pixel, nothing is reflected

INDEX.HTML

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
        'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
      }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'MY_ID_CONTAINER_GTM');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=MY_MEASUREMENT_ID_GA4"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'MY_MEASUREMENT_ID_GA4');
  </script>
```

MY SERVICES

```
track(labelTitle : string) {
    gtag('event', labelTitle, {});
    console.log('despues del click');
  }
```

WHEN I CALL MY SERVICES

```
this.analytics.track('NAME_LABEL_GTM');
```

Any ideas?

Try to make the query, check my tags in gtm and if they work in android but not in iOS, I also already made the respective configurations for iOS (NSAppTransportSecurity, GADIsAdManagerApp)